# How to repeatedly merge branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, version-control

We're using Mercurial where I work and I want to have a setup similar to how I used SVN:

- Trunk
- Tags

  - Production
- Branches

Since Mercurial supports branches natively, I know how to create a named branch, but I can't find any documentation on how to repeatedly merge 'Trunk' with 'Production'.

Quite simply, I want to have a development branch for normal work and a production branch that I routinely pull changes from the development branch into. How do I do this with Mercurial?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the previous poster mentioned, the transplant extension can be used for cherry-picking individual changes from one branch to another.  If, however, you always want to pull *all* the latest changes, the `hg merge` command will get you there.

The simplest case is when you're using clones to implement branching (since that's the use case Mercurial is designed around).  Assuming you've turned on the built-in [fetch](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/FetchExtension) extension in your `.hgrc` / `Mercurial.ini`:

```
cd ~/src/development
# hack hack hack
hg commit -m "Made some changes"
cd ../production
hg fetch ../development
```

If you're using local branches:

```
hg update -C development
# hack hack hack
hg commit -m "Made some changes"
hg update -C production
hg merge development
hg commit -m "Merged from development"
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like [`hg transplant`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/TransplantExtension)? That's what we use on our dev and prod branches.