# Trying to merge back from branch to main and close branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I've got a named branch (same repository) that was created in order to to spike something.  I've now decided that I want to move all the changesets created in the branch back into the main (default) and then close the branch.

I've tried a number of different things, including what was outlined in this post ([How to repeatedly merge branches in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223/how-to-repeatedly-merge-branches-in-mercurial)) but  I just can't get it working :(

Can anyone provide any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get more answers if you describe what happens (exact input/output) and define "can't get it working" a bit more...

Answer (score 8):

Merge the feature branch into default

```
hg up default
hg merge feature-branch-name
hg ci -m 'merged feature-branch-name into default'
```

Close the branch you don't want to use anymore

```
hg up feature-branch-name
hg ci --close-branch -m 'close feature-branch-name branch'
hg up default
```

Note that the close command doesn't have any disruptive effects on the repository history

It flags your branch as closed so that it won't appear in `hg branches` and `hg heads` commands output

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my problem using the link I mentioned in my question.  The steps described in the link had actually merged my changes across however I didn't realise as I was looking in the TortoiseHg UI and couldn't see the changes there.  When I performed `hg outgoing` via the command line it appears that the merge had worked correctly.